# unable to resolve class hudson.model.StringParameterValue

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, hudson, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am developing a groovy script in my pipeline A to get the latest revision of a svn repository ,save it into **revision** variable and append it to the version number tag in a POM file in Pipeline B. The idea is that this pipeLine A triggers pipeLine B if A is successfully run. When running the pipeLine A I get the following errors :

```
 1. unable to resolve class hudson.model.StringParameterValue
 2. unable to resolve class hudson.model.ParametersAction
```

Here is the code :

```
import groovy.json.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.util.*
    def revision = trunkRevision()
        def trunkRevision() {
            def ant = new AntBuilder() 
            ant.exec(executable: "svn", outputproperty: "output", dir: "."){ 
            arg(line: "info https://someURL/trunk -r HEAD")}
            svnInfo = ant.project.getProperty("output")
              def pattern = /Last\s+Changed\s+Rev:\s+(\d+)/ 
            def matcher = (svnInfo =~ pattern)
            def actualRevision =  matcher[0][1]
            def param = new hudson.model.StringParameterValue('actualRevision', actualRevision)
            def paramAction = new hudson.model.ParametersAction(param);
            def thr = Thread.currentThread();
            def currentBuild = thr?.executable;
            currentBuild.actions.add(paramAction)
            return actualRevision
```

What have Itried?

1. I tried running the script in a **Execute Groovy script** build step , specifying the groovy version and installation
2. I tried running the script in a **Execute System Groovy script** build step.
3. I tried installing different plugins that I thought might come in handy , for example **global-build-stats plugin**

Ps. When I run the exact same script in a **Execute System Groovy script** , I get an error saying :

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index is out of range 0..-1 (index = 0)
```

I don't know where I am wrong. I should also mention that everything is running on master , there's no slave in my pipeline!

Comment: If I understand correctly on one hand you are using traditional "clicked" jobs made in GUI and on the other you are trying to implant low level code there. Building pipelines this way is only asking for trouble.
I would strongly advice to go for [declarative](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline) or [scripted](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline) pipeline instead.

Comment: No in fact It worked , using another jenkins account and we are currently using this pipeline that I developed for getting the trunk revision and appending it to the version of the software in our company Jenkins account . My problem is that I don't understand why this scripts are not working on my local jenkins. I checked everything that I could but still don't have a clear Idea where the problem could be.

Comment: It really doesn't matter that it worked. To run this you need to approve series of code invocations, you need to keep it inside GUI job beyond version control repository and most importantly you cannot integrate any tests which would verify and document functionality. There is just no point in reanimating this Frankenstein.